# No entiendo como funciona esta sentencia

Tags: oracle, cursor

4.- Codificar el programa PL/SQL que solicite por pantalla un número de departamento y calcule la suma total de los salarios y comisiones de ese departamento. Después inserte la tupla correspondiente en la tabla TOTALES, previamente creada con la siguiente estructura:
deptno      number(3) 
total       number(10,2)

```
--CREATE TABLE TOTALES(deptno number(3), total number(10,2));
DECLARE
    cursor cur1(argu1 number) is 
        SELECT numde, salar, comis FROM temple WHERE numde=argu1;
    registro cur1%ROWTYPE;
    acu number(10,2):=0;
BEGIN
    OPEN cur1(&Numero_departamento);
    LOOP
        FETCH cur1 INTO registro;
        EXIT WHEN cur1%NOTFOUND;
        acu:=acu+registro.salar+nvl(registro.comis,0);
    END LOOP;
    INSERT INTO TOTALES VALUES(registro.numde, acu);
    CLOSE cur1;
END;
```

no entiendo que es acu, ni porque es registro.salar porque ese .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`acu` es una variable, en la que se suman los datos del loop
es algo equivalente a hacer `acu+=` 
Vemos que dentro de acu, aparte de sumar el valor anterior también suma el valor del la columna `salar` del cursor `registro`, ademas tambien se le suma `nvl(registro.comis,0);` esto es otro registro/columna del cursor que con la función `NVL` en caso de que el valor sea `null` lo remplazara por un `0`

Por lo que:

`acu` = variable

`registro` = cursor

`salar` = registro/columna de este cursor

Answer (score 6):

Creo que con la linea `acu number(10,2):=0;` se está declarando una variable`acu` que es de tipo numero con 10 digitos de los cuales 2 son decimales. Y diría que `acu` viene de `acumulado`.

La notación del `.` es para acceder a cierta columna/registro dentro de ese cursor. O sea, con `registro.salar` estoy accediendo a la columna `salar` del cursor `registro`

Esta linea `acu:=acu+registro.salar+nvl(registro.comis,0);` está sumando en `acu`, el valor de `acu` más el valor de la columna `salar` del cursor `registro`, más el resultado de `nvl(registro.comis, 0)` que imagino que representa alguna comisión. Esa función `nvl` lo que hace es devolver `0` si `registro.comis` es `null`. Así te aseguras de que siempre es un número y la suma funciona bien.

Al final parece estar calculando el gasto acumulado por departamento (salarios + comisiones) o algo así.